# How to round a double DOWN to the nearest Hundreth

Tags: java, variables, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to write a program where after the initial double is multiplied by the value of 0.175 it returns a value that rounds down to the nearest hundredth for example 895 * 0.175=156.62 instead of 156.625.

Comment: In which language?

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: Did you search? How about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)

Comment: Yeah but I can only find the round method which will round the value UP to the Nearest INTEGER

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.Math.floor` rounds down to the nearest integer.  So:

```java
Math.floor(100 * n) / 100.0;
```

should do what you want.  It multiplies the number `n` by 100 to truncate at the correct digit, then divides by 100.0 to undo the original multiplication.  It might not be the best way, but floor and multiplication/division are pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform first the double variable to a 2-decimal string representation then parse the string back to double.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING); //Set to RoundingMode.DOWN to round down
String result = df.format(895 * 0.175);
double product = Double.parseDouble(result);
System.out.println(product);
```